# How to improve handleBlur to ignore accepting hyphen as the character length in the input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Using the input field below, I want to display the confirm dialog to the user on handleBlur if their value is less than 9 digits or more than 10 digits.

```
<TextBoxField
  id="latitude-control"
  title="Latitude"
  name="latitude"
  value={latitude}
  maxLength={10}
  handleChange={this.handleChange}
  handleBlur={(e) => {
    if(e.target.value.length < 9 || (e.target.value.length > 9)) {
      this.setState({showConfirmDialog: true}),
      this.props.handleBlur(e);
    }
  }}
/>
```

My conditional works fine, but the only issue is if I enter a negative number then that hypen is also getting count as the character. What can I do in my handleBlur to not count hyphen as the character and only count numerical values for characters length?

Expected output:

```
12.1234561 -> length=10
-12.123456 -> length=9 instead of 10 // right now this is also counting as 10 characters
```

Comment: I see two possible ways to do it. Either strip out the negative sign or take the absolute value of of the value.

Comment: @JordanSchnur thank you for the response. I am not sure how would I do those 2 things. Can you please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regular expressions is one way to accomplish this.

```
<TextBoxField
  id="latitude-control"
  title="Latitude"
  name="latitude"
  value={latitude}
  maxLength={10}
  handleChange={this.handleChange}
  handleBlur={(e) => {

    var strippedLength = e.target.value.replace(/-/, '').length

    if(strippedLength  < 9 || strippedLength  > 9) {
      this.setState({showConfirmDialog: true}),
      this.props.handleBlur(e);
    }
  }}
/>
```

The code is fairly simple to follow.

*.replace* replaces a string with another string. In this example we used a regular expression which captures the ***-*** character and replaces it with nothing.

The two forward slashes define a pattern the regular expression.

I would read up on RegEx as it will certainly help you in the future.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: You would need to perform the replace on `e.target.value` not just `e`.

Comment: @Jordan - I still see the length as 10 for the input `-12.123456`. Looks like hpyen is still getting count as the character.

Comment: @dev101 Sorry, my regex shouldn't be in quotations. Try it now.

Comment: @JordanSchnur - yes, it worked now. Thank you so much. Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you have to do is to transform your value to absolute value.

```
<TextBoxField
  id="latitude-control"
  title="Latitude"
  name="latitude"
  value={latitude}
  maxLength={10}
  handleChange={this.handleChange}
  handleBlur={(e) => {
  let valueLength = e.target.value.length;
  valueLength = Math.abs(valueLength);
    if(valueLength < 9 || (valueLength > 9)) {
      this.setState({showConfirmDialog: true}),
      this.props.handleBlur(e);
    }
  }}
/>
```

Comment: It's impossible for a length to be negative.

Comment: This is not what the op was asking. This will get the absolute value of the length, which is always positive.

Comment: @JordanSchnur I think what he was asking is that getting the value without the initial hyphen and count only the numerical value . So I think `Math.abs()` can do that.

Comment: @JasperKetelaar Yes, I know it's impossible for a length to be negative. But maybe he was using some static value and checking for testing purpose. I was only answering from the perspective of the example that was given.

Answer (score -1):

You can strip the `-` from the value and check the length against that.

```js
const value = e.target.value;
const stripped = value.replace('-', '');
// Check length against stripped.length
```

Comment: Why is this downvoted? Curious if I made a mistake.